# Magento 2 API - declare @return JSON

Tags: magento2, orders, json

I'm playing with M2 API. I built a test module that returns specific Order items in JSON format. I set @return as 'string' (see screenshot below).

**Problem:** I'm getting error: Class string does not exist.

**Question:** how should I set @return in phpbloc to get it work properly?

[image]

Comment: You have to just remove @api and param integer $id  lline from comment and check.

Comment: Not sure why I should do that. The problem is with @return declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** function returns bunch of Order items so this is how @return should look like:

```
/**
 * Returns order details 
 *
 * @api
 * @param integer $id Order id.
 * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface[]
 */
```

It will automatically returns then in JSON format.